# Custom/Lambda layer with trainable weight

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to use the Keras.backend ops to write a function that I will wrap as a Lambda to use in my model.

There are two tensors, X and Y.  X is not trainable.  Y is trainable.

The python function that is wrapped is:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.activations import softmax

def _attention(inputs):
    X, Y = inputs
    attention_weight = K.dot(X, K.expand_dims(Y))
    attention_weight = K.squeeze(attention_weight, axis=-1)
    attention_weight = softmax(attention_weight, axis=-1)
    return attention_weight
```

which I wanted to wrap as:

```
Y = K.random_normal_variable(shape=(200,), mean=0.0, scale=1.0)
attend = Lambda(_attention)
attention = attend((X,Y))
```

When I call:

```
model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[attention])
```

I receive the message

`ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow`Layer`(thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("lambda_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)`

Do I really need to make a custom layer for the expand_dims, dot product, and squeeze method?  I know I could always reshape Y from (dim,) -> (dim,1) but I am still stuck with the squeeze.

Comment: What are your keras and tensorflow versions?

Comment: 1.8.0 TF - using the Keras package within Tensorflow

Comment: I think I can simplify it by using Dense(1, activation='linear') -> Flatten -> Softmax

Then TimeDistributed(Layer)